# For loops detects '\0' earlier than expected

Tags: c

According to the book "The C Programming language" written by K&R you can designate the end of a character array by writing '\0' to the last variable in the Array. After writing values to an array I ended it with a '\0' like so.

```
void itob(int value, char string[], int base)//writes integer c into string s with a base of b 

{
    int i;
    for (i=0; value; i++) {

        string[i] = value % base; //Writes remainder of value / base to character array
        value = value / base;
    }

    string[++i] = '\0'; // Ends string with EOF

}
```

Why then when I print the character's values in a for loop does it stop after a single iteration? Similarly when I print the string as a whole it stops after a single value.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    char string[MAXLINE]; // Max line defined as 1000
    int value;
    int base; 

    printf("Enter Value ");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    printf("\nEnter Base ");
    scanf("%d", &base);

    itob(value, string, base);

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) { 
    printf("Char %d = %d\n" , i, string[i]);}

    printf("\n%d in base %d = %s" , value, base, string); 


}
```

Output

```
Enter Value 27

Enter Base 5

Char 0 = 2

27 in base 5 is =
```

Comment: It is because **you didn't convert to characters** and 27 in base 5 is **`192`** which you convert backwards into `{2, 0, 1}`.

Comment: Oops meant to write **102** above :D

Comment: And the loop ends when it hits the 0 in the middle.

Answer (score 5):

Basically you are mixing integer values and char values.  In `itob` you are storing each digit as a number < base, not as an actual character, with the line `string[i] = value % base;`.  For known base <= 10 that line should be changed to `string[i] = '0' + value % base`.  Or for base <= 36 you could change that to the two lines `static char chars[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; string[i] = chars[value % base]`.  Either way make sure to check that base is in range before proceeding.

Then you must change the second %d in your printf to %c  to denote that you are printing a char.

Also note the number will be stored little-endian, least significant digit first.

Edit: Also change `string[++i] = '\0'` to `string[i] = '\0'` because `i` is already pointing to the index after all of the appended characters.

Comment: Your method of conversion is better than mine but I think you are misunderstanding. I am storing each value as a number knowingly. I was planing to convert them after I solved this current problem. How does the way I store a value in a string effect where my string ends?

Comment: The character '\0' is the numeric value 0, so the "string" "ends" when the first 0 occurs in the number.  You should pass `itob` an int pointer and fill it with the length of the array, and not terminate the array with any value.  Also imo since it is an array of ints you should consider using a different type than char, maybe uint8_t, just to be that much clearer about your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the string as char[], print as %c format and set the digit character like this.

```
string[i] = value % base + '0' ;
```

if you want to get the digit as int[], you can print as %d and set the digit you coded.
and the last character index is wrong.

string[i]='\0'; // not ++i

and you should reverse the string array or
print reverse.

```
for (i=strlen(string)-1; i>=0; i--)
printf("%c", string[i]) ;
```